# How do I check values of a particular array and increment or decrements it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a shopping basket in an array that I store in localstorage. How do I check if a particular value and either increment or reduce the values

Here is my code

I want to check if ProductID exists and then either add or subtract from it and then update localstorage

```
var Basket = {
    ProductID: product,
    Quantity: quantity
};

//STEP 2 - create an array 
//  
var BasketContents = [];
if (localStorage.getItem('BasketContents') != null) {
    BasketContents.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('BasketContents')));
}

//STEP 3 - create array of objects
BasketContents.push(Basket);
localStorage.setItem('BasketContents', JSON.stringify(BasketContents));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get around this by saving an object(call this object ALL) of objects, with the productId as the key of each object in the object(object ALL), or an Array of objects(each basket). The second one(array of objects) feels more intuitive so I would explain that.

1. fetch all the baskets you need and have them in an array like this:

```
const basket = [{productId: 2, quantity:5}, {productId: 6, quantity: 4}, {productId: 4, quantity: 18}, {productId: 3, quantity: 5}]
```

2. Save the basket in localStorage:
   ```localStorage.setItem('basketContainer', JSON.stringify(basket))````
3. Whenever you need to update this list/array, fetch the basketContainer from localStorage and loop through it.

```
const update = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basketContainer'))
update.forEach(x => {if (x.productId == 4) {x.quantity+=1}})
```

you can console the update at this point and you would see the change.

Please apply the samething for decrement too.

You could create a function like:

`````
const incrementDecrement = (list, action){ update.forEach(x => {if (x.productId == 4) {x.quantity`${action}`=1}})
}
// Where action is what determines if it is an increment(+) or decrement(-)
```

4. Once you're done, you can save the data back in your localStorage with the same initial name as it just overwrites the initial one.

something like this: ```localStorage.setItem('basketContainer', JSON.stringify(update))````

Goodluck!
By the way, you might want to read this: [stop_using_localStorage][1]


  [1]: https://dev.to/rdegges/please-stop-using-local-storage-1i04
`````

Comment: thanks for your asssitance, I have been trying all sorts with your code, the increment value of x.quantity+=1 does not increment it, but rather it appends it. e.g a value of one ends up as 11 instead of 2

Comment: @chicken, that should be easy. Just convert the x.quantity to a number first before having the addition. So you can have something like Number(x.quantity) += 1. Please do the samething for the comparison too. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simple way to do that

if the stored data is like this `{ ProductID: 241, Quantity: quantity }`

```
//check if BasketContents exists
if(localStorage.BasketContents){
    // if exists
    let BasketContents = JSON.parse( localStorage.BasketContents );
    // add 5 to productId
    BasketContents.ProductID += 5;
    // then update localstorage
    localStorage.BasketContents = JSON.stringify(BasketContents);
}
```

Comment: Your code has no coditions of checking if productID = variable before incrementing it

Comment: Your code has no coditions of checking if productID = variable before incrementing it and does not incxrement but rather appends it e.g. 1 becomes 11 instead of 2

Comment: easy make condition and parse the value with `parseInt() ` or `parseFloat()` or just put plus before the value like this `+vlaue` than increment your value . simple :)